# Postgresql Check if a row exists, given the data from a relative table

Tags: postgresql

We have three table in a Postgresql database. The one is the Routes, the other Locations and the other the RouteDetails.

Routes consist of Locations with a spesific order. This data is stored in RouteDetails table.

For example,
Lets say we have LocationA, LocationB and LocationC in Locations table.
A RouteA consist of this three Locations. 
The RouteDetails are (RouteA,1,LocationA), (RouteA,2,LoactionB), (RouteA,3,LocationC).
Meaning the first location of the route is Location, the second LoactionB and so on.

The problem:

How can we get with a query in databse if a Route exist if we have the Locations and their order?

The query must return RouteA only if we give (1,LocationA), (2,LocationB), (3,LocationC). Otherwise it must return empty.

UPDATE

Clodoaldo Neto is really close! But we don't want to check just count.

```
with given (seq, location) as ( values
    (1,'LA'), (2,'LB'), (3,'LC')
), route_details (route, seq, location) as ( values
    ('RA',1,'LA'), ('RA',2,'LB'), ('RA',3,'LC'),
    ('RC',1,'LA'), ('RC',2,'LB'), ('RC',3,'LC'), ('RC',4,'LD'),
    ('RB',1,'LB'), ('RB',3,'LC'), ('RB',2,'LA')
)
select route
from
    route_details
    left join
    given using (seq, location)
group by route
having (select count(*) from given) = count(*)
;
 route 
-------
 RA
 RB
```

How can we make this query match exactly this given locations?

Answer (score 0):

```
with given (seq, location) as ( values
    (1,'LA'), (2,'LB'), (3,'LC')
), route_details (route, seq, location) as ( values
    ('RA',1,'LA'), ('RA',2,'LB'), ('RA',3,'LC'),
    ('RC',1,'LA'), ('RC',2,'LB'), ('RC',3,'LC'), ('RC',4,'LD'),
    ('RB',1,'LA'), ('RB',3,'LC')
)
select route
from
    route_details
    left join
    given using (seq, location)
group by route
having (select count(*) from given) = count(*)
;
 route 
-------
 RA
```